# C end structure list

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, null

I want to make a list of structures in C. In my program, I read lines from a file and store information in structures (one structure per line). So my code is something like this:

```
struct myStruct *myStructList;

// Here is the parsing thing
```

And, at the end of the parsing, I try to do this:

```
myStructList[i] = NULL;
```

Where i is the next free position in the list (which has been already reserved with realloc).

This is the error I'm getting.

```
incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct myStruct’ from type ‘void *’
```

It appears I cannot do the NULL thing. My question is: what can I put there if it isn't NULL? How do I know the list has finished? I know I can keep a counter with the number of elements in the list, but I would like to avoid that.

Comment: I think its because your assigning the value NULL to a non-pointer. myStructlist[i] is a static variable.

Comment: Need more code for starters. I don't think you are fully describing what you intend to do. Also, you are assigning a value of NULL to a structure. You can't do things like struct myStruct = 2, etc.

Comment: Is your 'list' a linked list or an array?  It is looking more like an array.  There really isn't quite enough code for us to know what you're up to.  But the compiler is correct to complain about what you've written; it is just that we can't easily tell you what you should have written instead.

Comment: It's an array, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, unlike java - the array is holding elements by value, and not by reference.

So, you are trying to assign a pointer (address) to a struct, and this operation is undefined - so you get this error.

If you want to set an element to `NULL`, you should declare the array as `struct mySTruct*[]`, and assign pointers instead of values.

Answer (score 1):

`struct myStruct *myStructList;` defines a pointer to one or several objects of type `struct myStruct`. `NULL` is a constant that's guaranteed to be implicitly convertible to any pointer type. `struct myStruct` is not a pointer type.

There are two commonly used ways for you to use an end sentinel to signal the end of your array. The first one is to use an array of pointers to `struct myStruct`. This way, a NULL pointer can be used as an end sentinel.

The other option requires there to be a explicit NULL value for `struct myStruct`. You can thus define a NULL initializer like this (requires C99 or newer):

```
#define MYSTRUCT_NULL ((struct myStruct){ /* NULL initializer */ })
struct myStruct *myStructList = /* ... */
myStructList[i] = MYSTRUCT_NULL;
```

The contents of the array must be specifically compared against MYSTRUCT_NULL to find out the end sentinel.